# Radio button is not working in IE browser in dynamic data render from JSON

Tags: json, angular2-forms

I am working on dynamic data in which my `name` attribute can't bind in input tag in IE browser.

My code is here:

```
<input [id]="option.ID"
       (change)="question?.ShowText=='true' ? showHide($event) : question?.Value"
       [value]="option.Value"
       ngModel="{{question.Value}}"
       type="radio"
       [name]="question.Name"
       required="{{question.Validation.Required == 'required' ? 'true':'false'}}"
/>
```